# How do i check for a specific text in a file?

Tags: c

I'm reading a text file in C using `fgets(Array[100], 100, File);`.

Then I need to test if it contains a specific text such as Cow. I need to set Cow to be only the first character [C] and then write it to another file and so on.
I tried `strcmp(data, "Cow") == 0` but it never goes to the check.

I'm new to File I/O. Could you please let me know how I would do that? Also, the file has commas in between.

Comment: "but in never goes to the check". Shows us the code and we may be able to help. Please provide the code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: We can't tell you why code we can't see isn't working. If you want help, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Note that if you have `char Array[100]`, using `fgets(Array[100], 100, File)` is very incorrect.  In context, you should be using `if (fgets(Array, sizeof(Array), File) != NULL) { …process the data that was read… }`.  You may need to look at `strstr()` for your searching problem.

Comment: Learn more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)

Comment: I've added a sample code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for text contains a specific string then use strstr(data,"Cow") != NULL